# addFileAttachmentAsync call successful but Outlook 2016 says "Download failed"

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

The add-in I am developing uses the `addFileAttachmentAsync()` function to attach a text file. This function works correctly in OWA, but when I test the add-in in Outlook 2016 I am seeing some strange behavior.

The `addFileAttachmentAsync()` call appears to succeed passing the `asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded` check and the code within that block is executed. However, underneath the file name instead of seeing the file size Outlook says `Download failed`, but strangely it is still possible to click on the "failed" attachment and open it.

The URL used is a publicly accessible S3 bucket. I have one computer running Outlook 2016 where the `addFileAttachmentAsync()` call adds the attachment without problems, but two others display the `Download failed` string after adding the attachment. This behavior is consistent so it does not appear to be any type of network issue.

Is this a problem with the code in my add-in? Or is something going wrong with the Outlook 2016 clients on the other computers?

Comment: This could be a bug with Outlook 2016. Can you provide the following: 

1) Version # of Outlook 2016. (i.e. 16.0.8605.1000) that fails. And also the version #'s of the Outlook that succeed. 
2) the addFileAttachmentAsync() call that you are using, especially the http link to the file that you are trying to attach. (or if that information is not publically accessible, then a link that repros the issue) 
3) Do you know if you are on any insider channels? production channels? early release channels?

Comment: The Outlook 2016 client that's working is `Version 1701 (Build 7766.2099) Deferred Channel`. The other two Outlook 2016 clients are both running `Version 1707 (Build 8326.2096 Click-to-run) Current Channel`.

Here's the link you can use to test: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bess-outlook-addin/Test+File.txt

Comment: Additionally, is there a reason why we can't use a URL from the same domain as the web server our code is hosted on for `addFileAttachmentAsync()`? i.e. if the add-in code runs on `addin123.com` using `https://addin123.com/files/testfile.txt` as the URL for `addFileAttachmentAsync()` won't load the attachment, but posting the same file to an AWS S3 bucket and using that URL works fine.

Comment: So: `Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bess-outlook-addin/Test+File.txt", "test.txt"); `

This worked. Also this worked: 
'Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://i.imgur.com/tH8sYNt.png", "tiger.png");' 

However then I tried this (on a non-existent file): `Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bess-outlook-addin/Test.txt", "test.txt");` And THIS returned the error that you described (Download Failed), but the error html file is still uploaded anyway.

Comment: Is it possible that the webserver for the files that error out is returning a non-success html error code? (i.e. not 200, but 404, 500 etc?) I believe this causes the download failed error. Additionally you should be able to include any file that Outlook can reach (as long as it returns success) There should be no difference between https://addin123.com and another web server. If you can provide some more non-working links that you can repro with that one line code, then we can investigate some more.

Comment: Turns out the issue with the web server hosted file failing was because we were using self-signed certs for the local instance of the add-in. Once we tested it in our qa environment with actual certs we could use the file hosted by our web server. This also cleared up our issue with the download failing in the other versions of Outlook 2016. Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue in attaching onedrive file url( https://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/boardofdirectorsadvania/Shared%20Documents/Meetings/2018-05-29%20-%20test%20permission2/Test.pdf). Its attaching but says download failed with outlook native and does not work at all in outlook web. Its really strange as I can attach the same file from outlook UI.